# How to consume an exteral dll in universal windows application?

Tags: win-universal-app

I am creating a universal windows application.

Is there any options like adding an external c++/c# dll, to access required folders? Is it possible to consume an external dll's in universal windows app?

As we do in traditional c#, If any option is available- Please give me some reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing C Dlls from Windows 10 Universal App Across CPU Architextures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971006/referencing-c-dlls-from-windows-10-universal-app-across-cpu-architextures)

Comment: If its referenced from project file, will it be getting added under references part in visual studio?? I could not get it under references.